# Adding Editable Row into Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running into an error when adding a row into my data table:

[DataTable Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/243aW.jpg)

I want to add a row to the top of the table and then each column within the new row will have an editable text box to enter new info. I've looked online through a couple different links and nothing has really come close to what I'm looking for. I'm also pretty new as coding so I could be missing something really obvious!

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!--tab start-->
<div class="container-fluid full-width-container data-tables">
        <!-- Title -->
        <h1 class="section-title" id="services">
            <span>Data Table</span>
        </h1><!-- End Title -->

        <!--breadcrum start-->
        <ol class="breadcrumb text-left">
          <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li class="active">Data Table</li>
        </ol><!--breadcrum end-->

        <!-- table card -->
        <section class="row component-section">
            <!-- table card code and example -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="component-box">
                    <!-- table card example -->
                    <div  class="pmd-card pmd-z-depth pmd-card-custom-view">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="example-checkbox" class="table pmd-table table-hover table-striped display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <input type="button" value="Add Link" id="addbtn" />
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>First name</th>`enter code here`
                                <th>Last name</th>
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>Office</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                                <th>Start date</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Tiger</td>
                                <td>Nixon</td>
                                <td>System Architect</td>
                                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                <td>61</td>
                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Garrett</td>
                                <td>Winters</td>
                                <td>Accountant</td>
                                <td>Tokyo</td>
                                <td>63</td>
                                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Ashton</td>
                                <td>Cox</td>
                                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                                <td>San Francisco</td>
                                <td>66</td>
                                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- table card example end -->

                </div>
            </div> <!-- table card code and example end -->
        </section> <!-- table card end -->
</div>
<!--tab start-->
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example-checkbox').DataTable({
        responsive: false,
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            targets:0,
        } ],
        select: {
            style: 'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
        bFilter: true,
        bLengthChange: true,
        pagingType: "simple",
        "paging": true,
        "searching": true,
        "language": {
            "info": " _START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_ ",
            "sLengthMenu": "<span class='custom-select-title'>Rows per page:</span> <span class='custom-select'> _MENU_ </span>",
            "sSearch": "",
            "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search",
            "paginate": {
                "sNext": " ",
                "sPrevious": " "
            },
        },
        dom:
            "<'pmd-card-title'<'data-table-title'><'search-paper pmd-textfield'f>>" +
            "<'custom-select-info'<'custom-select-item'><'custom-select-action'>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
            "<'pmd-card-footer' <'pmd-datatable-pagination' l i p>>",
    });

    $('#addbtn').click(addrow);

    // addrow
    function addrow() {
        $('#example-checkbox').dataTable().fnAddData( [
            $('#fname').val(),
            $('#lname').val(),
            $('#position').val(),
            $('#office').val(),
            $('#age').val(),
            $('#start').val(),  
        ] );
    }
    // end addrow

    /// Select value

    $("div.data-table-title").html('<h2 class="pmd-card-title-text">Data table</h2>');

} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the add row function is adding nulls and does not have enough columns to match your definition (date col missing).

replace your addrow function with this and you will see it works...

```
function addrow() {
    $('#example-checkbox').dataTable().fnAddData( [
        'x',
        'c',
        'p',
        'l',
        'a',
        'z',
        'xyz'
    ] );
}
```

ALTERNATIVELY:  With columns.defaultContentOption set, any null or undefined value will be replaced with the value specified. No warning will be shown in this circumstances.

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgugjkrh/

However, you will need to address the following issues to correct the problem properly:

1: the Jquery selectors are not getting any data.

2: the add row function needs an empty string as the first value to prevent the row selector td from being populated.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I guess i forgot to delete an extra coloumn of data.. stupid me.